# What is a simple way I can position images in html5

Tags: html

Hey I have been trying to use the

```
style="position:absolute;TOP;55px right;170px"
```

format to position images but it does not seem to be working.

This is my code

```
<img style="position:absolute;TOP;55px right;170px" src="Apron On.JPG" height="250">
```

I was wondering if anyone who could tell me a simple way to position it on the screen. It is preferred no css but if there is I think I could handle it.

Comment: What you are using in your `style` attribute _is_ CSS.

Answer (score 2):

[CSS syntax reference](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_syntax.asp)
[CSS usage reference](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_howto.asp)

```
style="position:absolute;top:55px;right:170px"
```

Answer (score 0):

look at your syntax

==>

```
style="position:absolute;top:55px;right:170px;"
```

Some visual explanation here

==>

http://css-tricks.com/wp-content/csstricks-uploads/absolute-inside-relative2.png